# Building a simple array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this. Imagine there are 10 other keys like "Divertissement" in the principal array (this is only one branch of the principal array).

```
 array (size=8)
 'Divertissement' => 
    array (size=3)
  'Cosmic Top' => 
    array (size=3)
      'Cat' => string '7' (length=1)
      'Prix' => string '2.99' (length=4)
      'Desc' => string 'SOME TEXT'
  'Episodes' => 
    array (size=3)
      'Cat' => string '7' (length=1)
      'Prix' => string '3.99' (length=4)
      'Desc' => string 'SOME TEXT"
  'Rocket Deal' => 
    array (size=3)
      'Cat' => string '7' (length=1)
      'Prix' => string '0.99' (length=4)
      'Desc' => string SOME TEXT"
```

I am trying with no succes to create a new array that removes the first level array for each branch. So it would just remove "Divertissement", and start directty at Cosmic Top, Episodes, Rocket Deal as first level arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just merge every top-level entry to a new array:

```
$newArray = array();

foreach($yourArray as $item)
{

    $newArray = array_merge($newArray, $item);

}
```

Comment: was about to suggest exactly that

Comment: I don't get it :(. Can you use the elements of my array so I can understand better?

Comment: @Maxwell: sorry, I forgot to assign the merged value on each iteration, see my edit.

Comment: Nvm I got it! Thanks it works like a char, even though I don,t really get how it works lol.

Comment: Oh shit, I just got how it works, awesome function! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just pop it off:

```
$array = array_pop($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the array key values to a new array:

```
$newArray = $currentArray['Divertissement'];
```